# python : convert string to list of dictionaries

Tags: python

Following is a output from json.dumps which is assigned to a variable my_list

```
[
    {
        "diskGroupName": "DATA",
        "redundancy": "NORMAL",
        "disks": null,
        "diskPercentage": 80
    },
    {
        "diskGroupName": "RECO",
        "redundancy": "NORMAL",
        "disks": null,
        "diskPercentage": 20
    }
]
```

Since json.dumps() returns a string, I am getting the following output when I try to assign my_list to a dictionary key.

my_dict["grid"]["diskGroup"] = my_list

```
"grid": {
        "diskGroup": "[\n    {\n        \"diskGroupName\": \"DATA\",\n        \"redundancy\": \"NORMAL\",\n        \"disks\": null,\n        \"diskPercentage\": 80\n    },\n    {\n        \"diskGroupName\": \"RECO\",\n        \"redundancy\": \"NORMAL\",\n        \"disks\": null,\n        \"diskPercentage\": 20\n    }\n]"
```

Is there a way I can convert the above string(my_list) to a pythonian object and get the following assignment.

```
"grid": {
        
        "diskGroup": [
    {
        "diskGroupName": "DATA",
        "redundancy": "NORMAL",
        "disks": null,
        "diskPercentage": 80
    },
    {
        "diskGroupName": "RECO",
        "redundancy": "NORMAL",
        "disks": null,
        "diskPercentage": 20
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to load the string as json.

So, try this:

```py
my_dict["grid"]["diskGroup"] = json.loads(my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong function.

- `json.dumps` converts datastructures to strings.
- `json.loads` converts strings of json into actual objects.

You want to load your json from string, hence use `json.loads`.